# Can we get a custom logo in the top left like Stack Overflow has?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Here's another big question I have...
Who is actually building the site? Can the community help out?

I think it would be cool if we could have a custom logo in the top left like Stack Overflow.

Comment: We will get a custom logo and stylesheet once we graduate in a few years

Comment: Read: anywhere between a few weeks and a few decades

Comment: @mousetail I don't really understand fully how this works, so pardon my asking, but why do we have to wait to get a custom logo and stylesheet?

Comment: That's just the process. Private beta -> public beta -> full site. Only full sites get designs once they graduate.

Comment: Until we have proven ourselves to be worthy of being a full site we get the default blue styling. Note we might not make it, many sites get closed before reaching that point

Comment: @mousetail Ah, I didn't know that Betas could be closed! I'll try to write as many questions and answers as possible and promote the site! If we all do that hopefully we can survive.

Comment: @Hg0428 It's more about quality than quantity. Make sure to ask good questions and post good answers, and also downvote and close vote bad questions and bad answers

Comment: no [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/997587) joke? Also what exactly do you mean by "logo"? It sounds a bit like you're talking about the site banner.

Comment: related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368463/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259897/997587, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321059/997587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a custom logo we must first be a full and graduate site on the Stack Exchange Network. We are still in private beta. As to who builds the site? Well, SE Inc. makes the code but we **the community** builds the actual base of high-quality content. So, we don’t just help out, we build it. If SE could get that through their heads so much would be better,